# Lotus Notes Web application not launching

Tags: lotus-notes

I made a change in notes.ini file for HTTPDISABLEMETHODS=TRACE.
However, right after http restart, the notes application url stopped working.

I rolled back the changes and restarted the server, but it is still not working.

My first step is to launch the application on localhost and this is failing.

What are the steps to troubleshoot?

I have restarted notes service many times, and HTTP task is also running.
There were no other configuration changes done.

Error I get is - This site can't be reached. The connection was reset.
I am using Port 443.

Comment: Stopped working...no response?  404?  500 error?  Do other URLs work?  How about plain HTML files?

Comment: And what version are you asking about? Also, how did you set it? Via "set config" or via editing notes.ini? And how did you roll it back? Have you looked at the notes.ini file to see what's actually in there?

Comment: I edited notes.ini file.
First roll back - I removed the parameter and restarted the domino service.
Second roll back - My server team restore OS image backup from prior to the changes made.

By other URLs - you mean non-lotus notes sites? Yes, they work.
Plain HTML file works.

Comment: I enabled Port 80 and it seems to be working now. However, I must disable port 80, but it stops working again. Any suggestions?

Comment: You still haven't answered what version you are running or you see in the browser when you attempt the connection. Is it a 404? A 500? Something else. Have you loaded debug tools in the browser and looked at the security panel (that's what it's called in Chrome) to see what it says about the SSL handshake? Other than that, if you don't see anything there that gives you a clue, my only suggestion is to open an incident with HCL.